# Demoivre-Laplace - mailout response rate

Tags: probability

> A company sends out $1000$ invitation to customers to apply for a new credit card.  Historical data tells us that the response rate is $20\%$.  The company needs between 170 to 230 applications.  What is the probability that this will occur?  Do this with and without the continuous correction factor.

Is this the correct approach?
$n=1000$
$p=.2$
$np=200$
$s=\sqrt{.2\cdot.8\cdot 1000}=12.6491$

$\Phi\left(\frac{230-200}{12.6491}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{170-200}{12.6491}\right)=0.982294$
$\Phi\left(\frac{230.5-200}{12.6491}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{169.5-200}{12.6491}\right)=0.984101$

Comment: It looks fine. I have calculated with the continuous factor, too.